# Can i fill in a hole with dirt, growing grass over the top

Tags: towns

Often I'll mine out some rock on the surface layer. I want to replace the hole with grass so I can put farms on it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot build dirt or grass. I ran into the same problem when I wanted to build some farming islands.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but thanks. Hopefully they'll add it soon. It is still in beta after all.